# Only Show Duplicate Records Based on Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My goal is to find duplicates in the Identity column. I want to show only the identities and logins for users with duplicates. This is an example of the data that I have:

```
Id   Login        Identity
101  JamesT       15742
102  SarahS       21789
103  TonyP        15742
104  LizB         23444
105  EmmaT        14441
106  ToniaL       14441
```

I want to show something like:

```
Login        Identity
EmmaT        14441
ToniaL       14441    
JamesT       15742
TonyP        15742
```

This will display which users have duplicates sorted by the duplicate value. I'm having difficulty writing a query that will: a) only show duplicate values while b) also showing logins. Running a COUNT seems to require that I also group on Login, which will not work for this case.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(id) over (partition by identity) as minid,
             max(id) over (partition by identity) as maxid
      from t
     ) t
where minid <> maxid;
```

The above finds two different ids.  If you just want multiple rows, use `count(*)` instead:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(0) over (partition by identity) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```